# Compatibility Look-Keo/Look/SPD-Sl Plates & Pedals

Tags: pedals, compatibility, cleat

i got some old Look Road Pedals (*see picture*).

Now i found plenty of Cleats for cheap, but they all are for either `Look Keo`, `Delta` or `SPD-Sl`. 
Are those compatible? Did anything change from the old Look Pedals to the new Keo Pedals that could cause problems?

What cleats can i use?

[image: old look pedals]

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**Look Keo 2** and **Look Keo** are Look's current/previous range and they are compatible with each other.

**Look Delta** are Look's earlier range. I'm afraid they are not compatible with Keo's or Keo 2's

**SPD-SL** are Shimano's version of road pedals. These aren't compatible with Look products, (neither therefore are Look products compatible with them).

Checking out [Look's web site](http://www.lookcycle.com/en/us/route/pedales.html), you don't see Delta pedals on there any more, but if you look at the various Keo pedals, they are clearly a different shape to yours.

Doing a quick web search for Look Delta reveals many images, including some on [this page](http://www.sjscycles.co.uk/exustar-e-pr70-look-delta-pedals-prod24021/) (Exustar pedals which are compatible with Delta's - I haven't embedded the image here in case there are copyright issues). What do you think?

Note lastly that even within the "Look Delta" genre, you can buy different cleats. The difference between them is how much your foot is allowed to move whilst in the pedal (known as floating). Red cleats offer 9° float, whilst Black cleats are fixed (0°). The general rule is to go for the more flexible red cleats unless you have a reason to do otherwise. (This applies to spd-sl and keo also, in fact for spd-sl there are three options.)

Comment: Sorry, but i do not see such a big difference between the old Look and the ne Keo and Keo 2. Nor do i see big differences to Shimanos SPD-Sl System. The Time i-Clic looks mighty different but all those other systems look very much alike. Are you sure they are not compatible?

Comment: I didn't deliberately write a wrong answer, if that's what you're asking.

Comment: @AndreschSerj you could always buy the wrong cleats, try them, and report back. I would be astonished if they work, but you never know.

Comment: @Mσᶎ I am a big fan of throwing money out of the window and cycling with a horrible cleat/pedal combination just to prove a point ;-)

Comment: @AndreschSerj that's good to hear. In that case you'll be fine whatever you choose

Comment: @peteH - Look has a bunch of different pedal models so just to confirm... if I buy Look Keo Cleats they will be compatible with Look Keo *2 Max*, Look Keo *Classic 2*, Look Keo *Blade 2* ?

Comment: sorry I really don't know without looking it up, but given that some of Look's pedals are incompatible with others, I would be cautious.I don't really keep up with this stuff any more and so my knowledge may be dated. Can anyone help @maxwell out? Worst case, aski this as a standalonequestion - we used to answer what were probably a bunch of dups, I doubt that has changed

Answer (score 5):

These pedals appear to the Look PP66 - use the Delta cleats for them. The red cleats give you rotational float, black for fixed position.
As others have pointed out, the Keo cleats cannot be used, as they are smaller and a different shape than the Delta.

Answer (score 2):

Actually the `Look Delta` are the oldest [LOOK](http://www.lookcycle.com/de/de.html) System i could buy in any shop.
None of the shop owners/employees knew any other older system before keo.
And the Deltas worked for all the old LOOK Pedals i had (*i have 6 different old LOOK Pedals*).

Took them for a tiny spin (~40km) and had no problems whatsoever.

---

**Update:** Got an E-Mail from a brand manager for LOOK who wrote:

> keo cleats are NOT compatible with these old Look pedals. You will
>   need the Look Delta cleats which are available either in black (no
>   movement) or red (9° movement).
>   [..]